# How to rotate a blockquote by 180 degrees?

Tags: rotating, csquotes

I would like to rotate blockquote'd text by 180 degrees, but don't know how. Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
I would like to mirror (rotate 180 degree) this blockquote:

\blockquote[{\cite{nothing}}][]%missing ref doesn't matter here
{\lipsum[1]}

But I don't know how. The result from this test looks ugly 
(see the width, alignment and quotation marks for example):

\rotatebox{180}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \blockquote[{\cite{nothing}}][]%missing ref doesn't matter here
        {\lipsum[1]}%
    }%
}

Thank you very much for your help!
\end{document}
```

As blockquote seams to make some problems, I've used the simpler 
displayquote-environment (this workaround was suggested by UlrikeFischer, thanks).
The result looks better, but not fine (see the horizontal alignment and 
compare it to the original blockquote's position). The following MWE demonstrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\shortLorem}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut 
    purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, 
    felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, 
    nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec 
    vehicula augue eu neque.}

\begin{document}

\blockquote[{\cite{nothing}}][]%missing ref doesn't matter here
{\shortLorem}

%\noindent
\rotatebox{180}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \begin{displayquote}[\cite{nothing}]
            \shortLorem
        \end{displayquote}%
    }%
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Rotation and mirroring are not the same thing... Also, it looks like you have found out how to achieve what you want, but complain that it "looks ugly". So what precisely is the question? "How to make rotated text look better?"

Comment: It is not just ugly - it does not work (e.g. see the added quotation marks, or the distance to the next paragraph)

Comment: Don't use blockquote. That's a quite complicated command. Use e.g. the displayquote  environment. And don't forget a \noindent before the \rotatebox.

Comment: Thank you very much @UlrikeFischer! Using the displayquote-environment looks fine (but the quotation seems to look better aligned without the \noindet before \rotatebox - what am I missing?).

Comment: Interesting question. The list inside the parbox reduces its width. Not quite sure, if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: Note I updated the question: removed the confusing word "mirror" from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: rotated quotation]

This is not mirrored, of course. It is rotated through 180 degrees. But this seems to be what you are trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\shortLorem}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut
  purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
  felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,
  nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
  vehicula augue eu neque.}

\begin{document}

\blockquote[{\cite{nothing}}][]%missing ref doesn't matter here
{\shortLorem}

\noindent
\rotatebox{180}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \hfill
    \begin{displayquote}[\cite{nothing}]
      \shortLorem
    \end{displayquote}%
    \hfill
  \end{minipage}%
}%

\end{document}
```

[I only commented `fontspec` to avoid the slow compilation time since that wasn't essential to the question.]

Comment: Note that it would work better with `kantlipsum` than `lipsum` because the example doesn't load the correct hyphenation patterns for the latter. `microtype` would also improve things, of course. ;)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments by Ulrike, `blockquote` is not suited to this kind of manipulation. Have you compared the definitions? `blockquote` is doing complex things, including boxing stuff etc. If you want to do the manipulation, you don't want to be clashing with existing manipulation. Of course, you could redefine `blockquote`, but that's a different matter.